# How to redirect from subfolder with .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, frameworks, laravel

i have some question for you, pardon me before. I have some trouble when i want to redirect my website to another location. A url i have trying is like this :

```
http://localhost/mywebsite/public/example.html  => Default URL
```

I want to redirect my Default url to here:

```
http://localhost/mywebsite/example.html => What i want
```

My **.htaccess** code is :

```
Redirect 301 public /
```

im using **laravel** framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your .htaccess file in "public" folder:

```
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteRule (.*)$ /mywebsite/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the redirection to be transparent i.e. `/public` remains hidden in the URL, don't do a 301 as it does an external redirect. Use the following `RedirectRule` instead.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/public/ [NC]
RedirectRule ^mywebsite/(.*)$ mywebsite/public/$1 [NC,L]
```

This would serve `/mywebsite/page.html` silently from `/mywebsite/public/page.html`.

Comment: thats not work in my page, i get 500 server error, do you have others idea?

Comment: how if using rewriterule?

Comment: @ArryanggaAlievPratamaputra Add the rewrite condition I just updated.